MinimumOSVersion in 'MyProject.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework' is ''. in react native
While uploading on TestFlight, I have this error. I searched a lot but didn't helped any thing. I am using RN v.0.74.4.

Invalid minimumOSversion. Apps that only support 64-bit devices must
specify a deployment target of 8.0 later. MinimumOSVersion in
'CPOD_Recap_Revamp.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework' is ''.


I have tried several solutions, but nothing worked:

Deleting and install node_modules folder
Deleting and install package-lock.json
Deleting and install Pods folder
Deleting and install Podfile.lock
Defining minimumOSVerion in info.plist


Have you tried clearing derived data?

@RohitAggarwal Yes, I have tried clearing derived data, but no success. Though I have resolved this, and answer has been posted. Thanks!

I am able to resolve this by specifying MinimumOSVersion in info.plist of hermes.framework (info.plist path is quoted below). It could be a temporary fix;

/Users//Documents/React/CPOD_Recap_Revamp/ios/Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/Info.plist


Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/45823#issuecomment-2265127551
